# SQL 2008 - I need to count number of rows per employee in given time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has employee's daily totals with start date, I need to look back 3 months to see how many days an employee has worked.

Here is my sql query:

```
    SELECT
    EMPNO,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), STARTDATE,101),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERSONNUM) AS 'ROWCOUNT'
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE STARTDATE BETWENN DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
    GROUP BY EMPNO,STARTDATE
    ORDER BY EMPNO
```

Result

```
   EMPNO      STARTDATE               ROWCOUNT
   TEST108    09/13/2013              1
   TEST108    09/16/2013              2
   TEST108    09/17/2013              3
   TEST108    09/19/2013              4
   TEST109    09/04/2013              5
   TEST109    09/05/2013              6
   TEST109    09/06/2013              7
   TEST110    09/03/2013              9
   TEST110    09/04/2013             10
   TEST110    09/05/2013             11
```

Desired Result

```
   EMPNO           ROWCOUNT
   TEST108         4
   TEST109         3
   TEST110         3
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can there be multiple rows for one employee with the same STARTDATE, or why do you group over EMPNO, STARTDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CTE with `ROW_NUMBER` and `COUNT(*)OVER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT EMPNO, STARTDATE, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPNO ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC),
           [ROWCOUNT] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPNO)
    FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE
    WHERE STARTDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
)
SELECT EMPNO, STARTDATE, [ROWCOUNT]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8534/2/0)</kbd>

The `ROW_NUMBER` returns a number for every row in a partiton(similar to `GROUP BY EMPNO`) and allows to select all columns without needing to aggregate all. The `COUNT(*)OVER` returns the total-count of rows for each partition, so that what you want. I use the `ROW_NUMBER` just to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a count?

```
SELECT EMPNO, COUNT(EMPNO) AS [ROWCOUNT]
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE STARTDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
GROUP BY EMPNO
ORDER BY EMPNO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  EMPNO
    ,   [ROWCOUNT] = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.Employee
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY EMPNO
ORDER BY EMPNO --[ROWCOUNT] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
EMPNO,COUNT(STARTDATE)
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE STARTDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
GROUP BY EMPNO
ORDER BY EMPNO
```

Comment: You've got a typo in the select: "Betwenn" - otherwise I agree with this solution.